# Installing ruby 2.1.1 on ubuntu-12.04 -x86_64 getting error(3)

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I am installing ruby 2.1.1 using rvm on my ubuntu-12.04 -x86_64 m/c. I have already ruby 1.9.3 , 2.1.0 but for ruby 2.1.1 I am getting error.

I am using this command

```
  rvm install ruby-2.1.1 --verify-downloads 1
```

Error:

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/12.04/x86_64/ruby-2.1.1.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing requirements for ubuntu, might require sudo password.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/kiran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.1.1 - #downloading ruby-2.1.1, this may take a while depending on your connection...
curl: (3)  malformed
There was an error(3), please check /home/kiran/.rvm/log//*.log. Next we'll try to fetch via http.
Trying ftp:// URL instead.
curl: (3)  malformed
There was an error(3), please check /home/kiran/.rvm/log//*.log
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the log file mentioned by the error message, it may contain further, useful informations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this out:

1. Get the latest version of RVM:

   ```
   rvm get head
   ```
2. Reload the RVM:

   ```
   rvm reload
   ```
3. Install ruby 2.1.1:

   ```
   rvm install ruby-2.1.1
   ```

Comment: How do you get rvm on ubuntu

Comment: @TheJKFever, means you want to know how to install rvm on ubuntu?